How to send a message from PHP to a MS Teams Bot (Azure-Bot)?
I'm not able to trigger a message to a group chat from my Azure-Bot for Microsoft Teams from my PHP application and don't know why. Tried a lot of things now and asked GPT - but nothing worked. But when I'm using the Botbuilder framework in a javascript environment, the bot answers to my messages.
The credentials are valid and API permissions are also fine. The error I received:

URL: https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/19:c0e85885adfb4996aa6ec1a785010e6b@thread.v2/activities HTTP response headers: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Keep-Alive: true Content-Length: 61 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 MS-CV: VWPVTjV2B0+EmgoDiiux+w.0 Date: Fri, 07 Jun 2024 07:55:01 GMT Connection: close Response: {"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."} Array ( [message] => Authorization has been denied for this request. )

<?php
public function bot_reporting()
    {
        $params = array(
            'tenant_id' => 'xxx',
            'client_id' => 'xxx',
            'client_secret' => 'xxx',
            'bot_service_url' => 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea',
            'chat_id' => '19:c0e85885adfb4996aa6ec1a785010e6b@thread.v2',
            'bot_id' => 'xxx'
        );
        
        $this->load->library('bot', $params);
        
        try {
            $response = $this->bot->sendMessage('Test!');
            print_r($response);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>

<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bot
{
    protected $ci;
    private $tenantId;
    private $clientId;
    private $clientSecret;
    private $scope;
    private $botServiceUrl;
    private $chatId;
    private $botId;

    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();

        // Setze die Konfigurationswerte
        $this->tenantId = isset($params['tenant_id']) ? $params['tenant_id'] : '';
        $this->clientId = isset($params['client_id']) ? $params['client_id'] : '';
        $this->clientSecret = isset($params['client_secret']) ? $params['client_secret'] : '';
        $this->scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
        $this->botServiceUrl = isset($params['bot_service_url']) ? $params['bot_service_url'] : '';
        $this->chatId = isset($params['chat_id']) ? $params['chat_id'] : '';
        $this->botId = isset($params['bot_id']) ? $params['bot_id'] : '';
    }

    // Funktion, um ein Access Token von Azure AD zu erhalten
    private function getAccessToken()
    {
        $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$this->tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        $data = array(
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
            'client_id' => $this->clientId,
            'client_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'scope' => $this->scope
        );

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

        if ($result === FALSE) { 
            throw new Exception('Error retrieving access token');
        }

        $response = json_decode($result, true);
        if (isset($response['error'])) {
            throw new Exception('Error retrieving access token: ' . $response['error_description']);
        }

        return $response['access_token'];
    }

    // Funktion, um eine Nachricht zu senden
    public function sendMessage($messageContent)
    {
        $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();

        // Debugging: AccessToken ausgeben
        echo "Access Token: " . $accessToken . "\n";

        $url = "{$this->botServiceUrl}/v3/conversations/{$this->chatId}/activities";

        // Debugging: URL ausgeben
        echo "URL: " . $url . "\n";

        $data = array(
            'type' => 'message',
            'text' => $messageContent
        );

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken\r\n" .
                             "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode($data),
                'ignore_errors' => true // To capture the response in case of error
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        
        // Capture the HTTP response headers
        $http_response_header = isset($http_response_header) ? $http_response_header : [];

        if ($result === FALSE) { 
            $error = error_get_last();
            echo 'HTTP response headers: ' . implode("\n", $http_response_header) . "\n";
            throw new Exception('Error sending message: ' . $error['message']);
        }

        echo 'HTTP response headers: ' . implode("\n", $http_response_header) . "\n";
        echo 'Response: ' . $result . "\n";
        
        return json_decode($result, true);
    }
}
?>


When sending messages from PHP, make sure that the necessary headers, including authentication headers, are included in your HTTP request. Ensure that your bot has the necessary API permissions to send messages to the specified group chat.
Double-check the configuration of your Azure-Bot in the Azure portal. Ensure that the messaging endpoint URL is correctly set and matches the endpoint you are trying to send messages to.
